# Iterating through a HASH in perl

Tags: json, perl, hash

I used: `print Dumper $decoded`, where `$decoded` is the HASH variable and I got this as the output.

```
    $VAR1 = {
              'Case_345' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_512' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_534' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_552' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_578' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_466' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   },
              'Case_754' => {
                                     'Notes' => 'test2',
                                     'Submit_Date' => '2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC',
                                     'Last_Resolved_Date' => ''
                                   }
            };
```

This is what I tried using to output some values to test iterating through the HASH.

```
    foreach my $key ( keys %decoded )
    {
         print "key: $key, value: $decoded{$key}\n";
    }
```

It does not iterate at all through the `$decoded` variable. I am new to perl, could someone please help me out. If it helps I got this by converting a string with `JSON::XS::decode_json($json_str)`. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), especially the part about [hashes of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing is that `$decoded` is a *scalar variable* containing a *hash reference*, and is nothing to do with the hash variable `%decoded`. To access the hash that `$decoded` refers to you must *dereference* it, with `%$decoded`

You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of ***every*** Perl program you write, especially before asking others for help with it. It is a simple measure that, in this instance, would have caught the fact that you had used `%decoded` without declaring it

In addition, the *values* of your hash are more hash references, and printing them out will produce something less than useful like this

```
key: Case_466, value: HASH(0xbf4840)
key: Case_534, value: HASH(0xc6dc00)
key: Case_552, value: HASH(0x280fce0)
key: Case_512, value: HASH(0xbf4930)
key: Case_345, value: HASH(0xd4c2f0)
key: Case_754, value: HASH(0x280fdd0)
key: Case_578, value: HASH(0x280fd58)
```

Presumably you want the values of all the fields in each hash? To access the value of a hash element given a key and a reference to the hash you should write `$hashref->{key}`, so this code will dump the entire hash for you

```
for my $key ( keys %$decoded ) {
  my $data = $decoded->{$key};
  print "key: $key, values:\n";
  for my $field ( qw/ Submit_Date Last_Resolved_Date Notes / ) {
    printf "    %-18s => %s\n", $field, $data->{$field};
  }
}
```

#### output

```
key: Case_578, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_754, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_534, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_345, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_512, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_552, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
key: Case_466, values:
    Submit_Date        => 2015-11-21 00:53:22 UTC
    Last_Resolved_Date => 
    Notes              => test2
```